# volume scrubber flash actionscript3

Tags: flash, video

I'm trying to create a volume scrubber. I don't want to use the FLVplayback component because I want to customize my video.

On my stage I have a listener of MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP so when the user clicks on the volume scrubber but doesn't release on the scrubber, the startDrag() on the scrubber will still stop.

The problem is that if the user's mouse is up on anything besides the volume scrubber, the function attached to the stage will still execute. I don't know if this is a big deal, but I'd like to try to avoid it.

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stageUp);
```

so I thought this would work inside my stage function

```
function stageUp(e:MouseEvent):void{

    if(e.target == volumeScrubber){
      // volumeScrubber code that will execute
    }
}
```

But this is just as useless. For example, if the user drags the scrubber but "Mouseups" on anything but the scrubber, e.target will not be equal to volumeScrubber.

So how could I make the volumeScrubber code execute only when the user clicks on the scrubber?

Answer (score 0):

Something like that could perhaps help you:

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stageUp);

function stageUp(e:MouseEvent):void {
    // trace(e.target); // output : [object volumeScrubber]
    if (e.target == '[object volumeScrubber]') {
        // volumeScrubber code that will execute
    }
}
```